# NOOB question... variable for animate value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a variable that I would like to use to use as an animation value in pixels:

```
var thisAmount = maxScrollIncrements*DISPLAY_WIDTH 
$("#image").animate({left:"+=thisAmount", opacity:1.0}, "fast");
```

So in this case if "thisAmount" = 1200, I want the equvilant of:
 $("#image").animate({left:"+=1200px", opacity:1.0}, "fast");

I know this is simple but I am not getting it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The value after the colon is just a string, so you should be able to do:

```
$("#image").animate({left:"+=" + thisAmount + "px", opacity:1.0}, "fast");
```

(The "px" is optional.)

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate your variable to the string literal:

```
    $('#image').animate({ left: '+=' + thisAmount, opacity: 1.0 }, 'fast');
```